# Laravel buscar elementos en una colección

Tags: laravel

Tengo un método en un controlador que obtiene dos colecciones de una tabla de clientes: una con todos los clientes, y otra con los clientes asociados a una tienda, de una tabla de tiendas. La relación es `m-n`, mediante una tabla pivote.

```
public function shopCustomers($id)
{
    $clientesAsociados = Shop::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->customers;
    $clientes = Customer::withTrashed()->get();
    dump($clientes, $clientesAsociados);
}
```

La cuestión es que en la colección de todos los clientes necesito marcar los que están en la colección de asociados, porque, al pasar a una vista, van a salir en un select múltiple, y deberé añadirle `selected` a los que ya estén seleccionados.

La pregunta es ¿tengo que manipular las colecciones como matrices de forma artesanal para marcar los seleccionados? ¿Hay alguna solución adecuada, con prestaciones propias de Laravel, para hacerlo?

Como veis, estoy usando el método withTrashed() porque uso soft delete para las tablas. Todas ellas (tiendas, clientes e, incluso, la tabla pivote), tienen el campo deleted_at. En la tabla pivote lo añadí para guardar un histórico de las asociaciones desactivadas.

Comment: revisé la edición a la respuesta de HCK y no es correcta ni bien vista así no funciona el sitio; el te dió la respuesta y tu la aceptaste con eso basta

Comment: si tienes algo mas que comentarle entonces usa la zona de "comentarios" debajo de la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías marcar los elementos haciendo uso de las funciones [`Map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map) y [`Contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-contains), propias de [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods):

```php
public function shopCustomers($id)
{
    $clientesAsociados = Shop::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->customers;
    // marcando clientes:
    $clientes = Customer::withTrashed()
                          ->get()
                          ->map(function ($cliente) use ($clientesAsociados) {
                                $cliente->is_associated 
                                      = $clientesAsociados->contains('id', $cliente->id))
                                      ? true
                                      : false;

                              return $cliente;
                          });
}
```

---

PD: Acá estoy usando una manera resumida del `if`/`else` para asignarle un valor  a `$cliente->is_associated`. Es característico de PHP `7+`. Si quieres más información respecto a esto puedes revisar [este artículo](https://www.neoguias.com/if-abreviado-en-php-el-operador-ternario/).

---

---

## Update

Ahora que lo noto, ni siquera es necesario el `if`/`else` pues el método de por sí retorna un `boolean`, lol:

```php
public function shopCustomers($id)
{
    $clientesAsociados = Shop::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id)->customers;
    // marcando clientes:
    $clientes = Customer::withTrashed()
                      ->get()
                      ->map(function ($cliente) use ($clientesAsociados) {
                              $cliente->is_associated =
                                   $clientesAsociados->contains('id', $cliente->id));

                              return $cliente;
                          });
}
```